# Properly squish a pgfplot bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart with the following lengthy data:

```
Character   X-Position  Probability
space   1   0.18211
e   2   0.10083
t   3   0.07298
h   4   0.06721
a   5   0.05862
o   6   0.05435
n   7   0.04792
i   8   0.0421
s   9   0.04067
d   10  0.03916
r   11  0.03827
l   12  0.02508
f   13  0.01982
m   14  0.01964
u   15  0.01781
w   16  0.01676
p   17  0.0163
comma   18  0.01394
c   19  0.01391
y   20  0.01309
1   21  0.01165
g   22  0.0111
b   23  0.01075
v   24  0.00551
N   25  0.00544
:   26  0.00537
I   27  0.00493
.   28  0.00491
k   29  0.00488
2   30  0.00423
A   31  0.00395
;   32  0.00357
L   33  0.00304
3   34  0.00246
G   35  0.00166
4   36  0.00163
5   37  0.00143
7   38  0.00138
8   39  0.00128
6   40  0.00122
0   41  0.0011
9   42  0.00102
J   43  0.00072
S   44  0.00059
B   45  0.00058
-   46  0.00052
j   47  0.00047
x   48  0.00046
T   49  0.0004
W   50  0.00038
?   51  0.00037
H   52  0.00029
F   53  0.00028
O   54  0.00027
Y   55  0.00022
M   56  0.0002
R   57  0.00019
C   58  0.00018
q   59  0.00017
!   60  0.00013
E   61  0.00011
Z   62  0.00011
z   63  0.00009
'   64  0.00004
D   65  0.00004
K   66  0.00004
P   67  0.00003
(   68  0.00002
)   69  0.00002
U   70  0.00001
```

I put that data in a file called "my.dat", and made my Latex file in the same directory:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    xlabel=Character, ylabel=Probability
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={my.dat}{Character}
]
\addplot table [
    x=X-Position,
    y=Probability
] {my.dat};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is awful:

[image]

With Excel I know how to make the chart look decent. The letters come out a bit squished, so I stretch the chart:

[image]

But notice how it tried on its own to make the bars as thin as possible to fit it all in the chart. How do I make pgfplots try harder to make everything fit?

Alternatively, it would be nice to know if there were a way to make a bar chart wrap itself, as in cut into portions and each displayed next to/on top of the other.

Has anyone who can help had experience with pgfplots trying to graph lots of data?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the bars automatically fit into a plot of a specified width? Or do you just want to know how to specify the bar width?

Comment: you could use `width=<length>` to set the width of the graph, and `bar width=<length>` to set the width of the bars. For rotating and shrinking the labels, you can use `x tick label style={font=\small,align=right,rotate=90}`.

Comment: @Jake- I want a way to squeeze all of the graph into a smaller area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it fit in the given space, but then the `x tick label`s are `tiny`

### Code 1

```
\begin{axis}
[   ybar,
  xlabel=Character,
  ylabel=Probability,
  xtick=data,
  xticklabels from table={my.dat}{Character},
  bar width=2pt,
  width=0.95*\textwidth,
  x tick label style={font=\tiny,align=right,rotate=90},
  enlarge x limits=0.01,
  enlarge y limits=0.01,
]
\addplot table
[   x=X-Position,
  y=Probability
] 
{my.dat};
\end{axis}
```

### Result 1

[image]

---

But questions remain:

- do you have to do this on `letter paper`?
- do the margins need to be this big?
- wouldn't a logarhitmic plot be better, as the right side of the diagram is basically empty?

For comparison:

### Code 2

```
\usepackage[margin=0.6in]{geometry}
```

...

```
\begin{semilogyaxis}
  ybar,
  xlabel=Character,
  ylabel=Probability,
  xtick=data,
  xticklabels from table={my.dat}{Character},
  bar width=5pt,
  width=0.95*\textwidth,
  x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,align=right,rotate=90},
  enlarge x limits=0.01,
  enlarge y limits=0.01,
]
\addplot table
[   x=X-Position,
  y=Probability
] 
{my.dat};
\end{semilogyaxis}
```

### Result 2

[image]

---

As suggested by **Jake**, a scatter plot is probably better that a bar plot for this case:

### Code 3

```
\begin{semilogyaxis}
[   scatter,
    scatter src=y,
    only marks,
  xlabel=Character,
  ylabel=Probability,
  xtick=data,
  xticklabels from table={my.dat}{Character},
  bar width=5pt,
  width=0.95*\textwidth,
  x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,align=right,rotate=90},
  enlarge x limits=0.01,
  enlarge y limits=0.02,
  grid=major,
  colormap={portal}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,128,0); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,255)},
  colormap name=portal,
]
\addplot table
[   x=X-Position,
  y=Probability
] 
{my.dat};
\end{semilogyaxis}
```

### Result 3

[image]

Comment: +1, but logarithmic bar plots are a Bad Idea, since they don't have a natural origin. See http://bzintelguru.com/blog/bar-chart-with-a-log-axis-never-says-the-biz-intel-guru/ for a nice explanation.

Comment: @Jake: In the linked example I agree that it's a bad idea. But tell me, how are you going to read of the values in the first example? By comparing the lengths of the bars? As the given data streches four orders of magnitude, I think a logarithmic plot is justified.

Comment: A logarithmic plot is indeed justified, but not a logarithmic *bar* plot. A scatterplot would work better in this case, in my opinion.

Comment: @Jake: Okay, that we can agree upon.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Environment semilogyaxis undefined.` Did you have to include anything besides pgfplots?

Comment: @NateGlenn: No. Which version do you use? I'm using PGFplots 1.4.1 (but probably I should upgrade again as I just saw that 1.6.1 is the current version).

Comment: @TomBombadil: I'm not sure. MikTex tells me it was downloaded/install on the 16th of this month.

Comment: It is written to your `.log` file. For me, this is `Package: pgfplots 2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1 (git show 1.4.1-1-g64c9e95 )`. It's also definitively part of the package, have a [look at the documentation](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), section 4.1 at page 21.